# Harvest a native (x86 or x64) COM Dll's registration information with WIX Heat (v3.5, v3.6)?

Tags: com, wix, registration, heat

I have a new C++/ATL DLL (x86 and x64) that I'd like to include in an installer and was hoping Heat.exe could save some effort.

Comment: Funny how that happens... I tried this on the x86 version of the [native] DLL, and it worked. To make sure I wasn't going crazy, I tried once again on the x64 version of the DLL and it failed. I don't know if this is a bug in Wix (3.6.1811) or if it is expected with Heat and native .dll's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heat doesn't support x64 self-reg extraction. In general, you can use the extracted x86 registration for both x86 and x64 -- the WiX COM elements like Class work for both flavors.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bob. Clarity is priceless! I appreciate your confirming this for me. The heat output generated when running it against the x86 DLL did indeed provide the COM reg data I needed. It worked for both of the x86 and x64 installers. Have a great weekend, sir! Cheers :)